# How to post SOAP request in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, post

How should I make this request on iOS in Objective C?

```
POST /WS/CustomerServices.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: mesereser.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <AddContactToGroup_BasicInfo xmlns="http://mesereser.com/">
      <oLogin>
        <UserName>string</UserName>
        <Password>string</Password>
      </oLogin>
      <iUserID>int</iUserID>
      <sGroupName>string</sGroupName>
      <oContact>
        <FirstName>string</FirstName>
        <LastName>string</LastName>
      </oContact>
    </AddContactToGroup_BasicInfo>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try this code :

```
NSString *urn = @"urn:IServiceFactorySilverlight";
NSString *namespace = @"";

NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<%@ %@>\n"
                         "%@"
                         "</%@>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n"
                         ,method, namespace, params, method];


NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[soapMessage length]];
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",urn,method] forHTTPHeaderField:@"soapaction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to send to server:

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                     "<soap:Body>\n"
                     "<%@ %@>\n"
                     "%@"
                     "</%@>\n"
                     "</soap:Body>\n"
                     "</soap:Envelope>\n"
                     ,method, namespace, params, method];                             ];
NSLog(@"soapMessage: \n%@",soapMessage);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"???.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/GetMessages" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if(theConnection )
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
else
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
```